# how to edit a trigger set by another user on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a trigger set by another user. I tried to edit or delete it but there is no option for that actions. See the picture below. Is there any way to edit it?

[image: Trigger setting]

Comment: No `````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: A Trigger belongs to the user that created it. Typically, only the creator of a trigger can edit or delete it. However, there is one possible exception. If you are the admin of a GSuite Domain it is possible to configure a service account to act on a user's behalf, and set up a custom Web App to manage triggers. But that's only applicable to users within that domain.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Thank you. I don't have admin account. The user who set the trigger left project. The trigger looks still working. But, I want to delete it to create new one by my account. Is there any way to do it? If admin deletes the account, the trigger will be automatically deleted?

Comment: @Herbert Are you working under a GSuite domain? If so, then you need admin access to pull that off. If you and the creator of the trigger are using consumer accounts (non-GSuite domain accounts), then you don't have an option to delete that trigger. Consider making a copy of the sheet and creating your own trigger on the new sheet.

Comment: Hello Herbert, just like @TheAddonDepot said, have you tried to copy sheet and creating your own trigger? Does this work for your case? Cheers!

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Yes, I am working under GSuite domain. I would like to do the way that you told me. _it is possible to configure a service account to act on a user's behalf, and set up a custom Web App to manage triggers._ Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @ale13 Thank you. I don't want to change instance of the spreadsheet by copying it to create new one because end users have been using this spreadsheet already.

Comment: @Herbert As I said before you need an admin account to do that. Since you don't have that level of access I can't help you beyond the advice I've already given.

Comment: @Herbert Maybe there is another way to approach this. Is the account of the user who left the project under the same GSuite Domain? If so, your admin should be able to reset the user's password and provide you with the necessary credentials to access the account directly.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot yes, that's good idea :) that _your admin should be able to reset the user's password and provide you with the necessary credentials to access the account directly_. I will ask admin for that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps Script triggers belong to the user who created them so unfortunately there is no direct way for you to edit/delete those triggers.

**Possible solution**

If the account of the user who created the triggers is under the same G Suite domain you should be able to contact your G Suite administrator in order to reset their password. In this way, you *may* be able to get access to the new credentials and change the triggers yourself.